# Finding the derivative with the indicator function?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the derivative of functions that depend on the indicator function. For example, I want to find the value of $x$ that maximizes the following function:

$f(x) = g(x) - b\cdot x - c\cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{x \text{ is divisible by 10}\}} $

Where $\mathbb{1}_{\{\cdot\}}$ is the indicator function which takes the value 1 if the expression in brackets holds and 0 otherwise.

Comment: That indicator function is zero everywhere but $x=10k$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ where it takes value $1$. So it’s not continuous at any multiple of $10$. Proof: fix the multiple $k$ and let $\delta>0$. Then $|\mathbb{1}(x)-1|\geq 1$ for any $x\neq 10k$ such that $0<|x-10k|<\delta$ since from either side we approach $10k$, we know $\mathbb{1}(x)=0$, and this shows the limit does not exist, hence continuity must fail. So it certainly cannot be differentiable at those points either.

Comment: Got it. So in cases like this one, is there any rule of thumb to find the value that maximizes the function? (I am thinking about finding the solution analytically, not via numerical simulation). Thanks!

Comment: you can certainly try to locally maximize $f(x)$ on each interval $(10k,10(k+1))$ $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ using standard calculus, given $g(x)$ is sufficiently nice. But an analytic solution for a global maximum is going to be difficult or impossible due to the irregularities mentioned in my above comment. Do you have a specific $g(x)$ in mind?